# Dart MIME type changed to vnd.dart by spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, header, dart, content-type

I'm trying to serve DART application from spring.
Dart files a mapped as resources.

Spring automatically adds "vnd" to MIME type. So instead of "application/dart" I get "application/vnd.dart".

This works fine as long as **X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff** header is disabled by setting

```
http.headers().contentTypeOptions().disable();
```

But if I still want to use nosniff, how do I make Spring leave content-type as "application/dart"?

Answer (score 1):

As I found, MIME types for extensions should be set in servlet configuration, not in Spring.
In web.xml added

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>dart</extension>
    <mime-type>application/dart</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```